# Migrating lock to TPL

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, task-parallel-library

In normal C# we write

```
int DoSomething(){/*...*/)};

lock(mutex)
{
    return DoSomething();
}
```

to ensure in all cases the `mutex` is released.

But if the signature of `DoSomething` changed to

```
Task<int> DoSomeThingAsync(){/*...*/};
```

Does the following code

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Monitor.Enter(mutex);
    return DoSomethingAsync();
}).Unwrap().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    Monitor.Exit(mutex);
    return t;
}).Unwrap();
```

do similar things? Is it guaranteed to release the `mutex` whenever it was entered? Are there any simpler way to do so? (I am not able to use the `async` keyword so keep thinking in TPL only)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `Monitor` in that way because `Monitor` is thread-affine and in your case the task and continuation may run on different threads.

The appropriate synchronization mechanism to use is a `SemaphoreSlim` (which isn't thread-affine) set to 1:

```
public SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

_semaphore.Wait();
return DoSomethingAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    _semaphore.Release();
    return t.Result;
});
```

As long as you don't use one of the `TaskContinuationOptions` such as `OnlyOnFaulted` or `OnlyOnCanceled` the continuation would always run after the task has completed and so the semaphore is guaranteed to be released.