# TPL and Monitor in PCL

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, blocking, portable-class-library

So I'm writing a client API PCL (.NET 4.5, SL 5, Win8, WP8.1, WP SL 8) library and I've decided that I'm only going to allow one HTTP request at a time. Currently I use the TPL to do them:

```
Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpReq.BeginGetRequestStream, httpReq.EndGetRequestStream, null).ContinueWith<Task<WebResponse>>((requestStreamTask) =>
{
    return Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(httpReq.BeginGetResponse, httpReq.EndGetResponse, null);
}).Unwrap().ContinueWith<HttpWebResponse>((getResponseTask) =>
    {
        return (HttpWebResponse)getResponseTask.Result;
    });
```

So I want to add locking to prevent more than one request from going at once. I know I could simply call `Monitor.Enter` before I start and call `Monitor.Exit` in the last `ContinueWith`. But based on [Migrating lock to TPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898058/migrating-lock-to-tpl), I can't use `Monitor` like that because of threading issues possibly. I have no issue using a different blocking object like that post recommends but as far as I can tell in my PCL the only lock I have available is Monitor.

So what should I do?

**EDIT:** After talking with Yuval Itzchakov below I've realized the reason I only have the `Monitor` class for syncing is because I have Silverlight 5 support in my PCL. If there is no other way I'll look into dropping support for SL5 but I'd rather not.

**EDIT2:** After messing around I realized that I do have the `ManualResetEvent` class, could I use that?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use a producer/consumer pattern, where a single thread is responsible for all HTTP requests - you create a queue of them, and the thread process the queue. You could look at `BlockingCollection<T>`, or possibly even TPL Dataflow.

Comment: I looked to use `BlockingCollection<T>` but it's not supported in the PCL configuration I'm using. Same with TPL Dataflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're writing a PCL and including some older platforms (specifically, SL5), your choices are a bit limited. TPL Dataflow is not supported on SL5, and neither is `SemaphoreSlim`.

However, [`HttpClient` is](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http), and [so are `async`/`await`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/). These allow your code to be far, far cleaner than `Task.Factory.FromAsync` + `Unwrap` + `ContinueWith`.

For portable `async`-ready synchronization and/or producer/consumer queues, I recommend my own [AsyncEx library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/). In this case, an `AsyncLock` should suffice; it can be used in a similar way to `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
private readonly AsyncLock _mutex = new AsyncLock();

public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url)
{
    using (await _mutex.LockAsync())
    {
        return await _client.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently looking in to switching to using Async/await and `HttpClient` for the library. Primary reason I'm not jumping to is doing so would require rewriting massive amounts of code and that's not something I'm just going to do without thinking it out first. Your AsyncLock though does look like just what I want, hmmmmmmmmm

Comment: @shmuelie: You *can* use `ContinueWith`; it's just that `await` is a lot easier.

Comment: you mean I can use your `AsyncLock` with `ContinueWith`, You might be the winner then!

Comment: I'd recommend any new code you write use `await`. I'm just saying you can add `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` and use `await` for new code without rewriting "massive amounts of code".

Comment: I personally don't like the idea of having the mix of ways of doing things but short term I may just do that

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in that answer I used `SemaphoreSlim` that states in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it's supported in PCL, so you can use it instead of `Monitor`.

Secondly, as [Jon Skeet pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164604/tpl-and-monitor-in-pcl#comment42821813_27164604) you can use TPL Dataflow's `ActionBlock` (also supported in PCL( with `async-await`:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<HttpWebRequest>(request => 
{
    var result = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    // handle result
}

HttpWebRequest newRequest = // ...
block.Post(newRequest);
```

The block handles all requests one at a time and you add new onces using `Post`.

Comment: I looked to use `SemaphoreSlim` and TPL Dataflow but neither are supported in the PCL configuration I have.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using the quite verbose `FromAsync` pattern, you can use [`HttpClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) and `SemaphoreSlim` (as Arnon and Jon mentioned) which support PCL:

```
private SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

private HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

public async Task SendRequestAsync(HttpWebRequest request)
{
      await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
      try
      {
         return await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
      }
      finally
      {
         _semaphoreSlim.Release();
      }
}
```

Comment: While `SemaphoreSlim` is not supported in the PCL configuration I am using, using HTTP client is an interesting idea. Even more interestingly to me is that it requires other packages that give my configuration Async/Await which would simplify my code base on so many levels. So I'm going to have to give this a look.

Comment: What do you mean by *"PCL configuration im using*"?

Comment: I have the PCL set to support .NET 4.5, Silverlight 5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1, and Windows Phone Silverlight 8. By setting it to all the what APIs I have is very very restrictive.

Comment: I see. I think whats limiting you is SL5. I see all other platforms are supported.

Comment: Could be, I haven't looked into what's limiting me. If that is the limiter I may give in and drop support for it.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Just removed Silverlight 5 from support and got access to `SemaphoreSlim`. So if there is no other way I may just have to drop Silverlight support.